# Measuring a DiV's width, or grabbing JS variables in Python.

Tags: javascript, python

I'm working on a website in Python. It's all going well so far, however:
the template is made up of 300 pixel blocks. Picture it thus:

```
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
OOOOO
```

Now, previously I had an enclosing div set to 1500px width. This meant that I could check whether the object was divisible by 5 in order to generate more blocks if there weren't enough to make it seamless. For example, say I have 7 pieces of generated data:

```
OOOOO
OO
```

Now this just looks ugly, so we generate additional empty blocks until the total is divisible by five:

```
OOOOO
OOXXX
```

This is fine if you're working with a fixed width.
The thing is, I want to go with a variable width (100%). I can then simply perform Div Width / 300px to find out at which point I need to start printing additional blocks.

**So, the question:**
This means I need to do one of two things:
 - Find a way Measure a div's width in Python (is this even possible?)
 - Pass a variable from Javascript to Python.
     I have a JS script that can measure the div's width. The variable is sitting there in Javascript and can be printed to the page fine. But how can I then pass this data on through to Python, so I can work with it?

Thanks for looking; hope it's not too confusing!

Comment: Whoops! Went back and edited that. Got mixed up between the template as it currently looks and how it was. Thanks for your valuable contribution, though, gnibbler. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it all in JavaScript is generally going to be the neatest way to do it. Make it so that it'll sort of work without JavaScript, and that JavaScript will fix it up (generate the empty blocks in JS). If they're the same size, you could also use a repeated background image to simulate the empty blocks, but that probably won't look nice unless you do it very carefully, when you're doing it with variable width.